# JPAでデッドロックを検出する方法

Tags: java, java-ee, jpa

JPA（EclipseLinkを使っています）でデッドロックを検出する処理を書きたいのですが、どのようにするものなのでしょうか？
DBMS（SQLServer, Oracle, PostgreSQLを対象としています）側にデッドロック検出の機能はありますので、それによるロールバックの際に、JPAが何らかの例外を投げてくれるのではないかと思っています。
ただ、どんな例外なのか？
デッドロック検出によるものだと判別できるのか？
という辺りが分からず、どなたかご存知であれば、教えていただきたいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EclipseLinkから呼び出される各RDBMS用のJDBCドライバーの実装(どの例外を返すか)に依存しますが、[SQLTransactionRollbackException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/7/api/java/sql/SQLTransactionRollbackException.html)をcatchするようにしておけば、いいと思います。MySQL 5.1.73の場合は、これを継承する`MySQLTransactionRollbackException`がスローされました。

実際にデッドロックを起こすコードを書いて実験してみると、分かります。

私が書いた記事ですが、参考まで：
https://qiita.com/tamura__246/items/d8f168b62617aef6c177

例外処理はこんな感じでしょうか。

```
} catch (SQLTransactionRollbackException e) {
    log.error("SQLTransactionRollbackException occurs: ", e);
    rollbak(conn);
} catch (SQLException e) {
    log.error("SQLException occurs: ", e);
    rollbak(conn);
} finally {
    close(stmt);
    close(conn);
}
```

Comment: `SQLTransactonRollbackException`について、こちらの記事も読んで納得しました。ありがとうございます。http://d.hatena.ne.jp/iad_otomamay/20070316/1174053449